# How to tell if a Windows 7 installation is genuine

Tags: windows-7, windows-genuine-advantage, piracy

I was asked to take care of some suspicious looking Windows 7 machines in the University. They all have the Windows Vista sticker but all all running Windows 7 Ultimate. If they are running on pirated software, this will bring me trouble (they were donated by another department which is not IT-related). How can I tell if they are running a legitimate copy of Windows 7 and not just some cracked version which is blocking Microsoft's checks?

Comment: Determine what the license key is.  Format the machines.  Attempt to activate the machines.  If they activate then the license is genuine.  If they cannot be activated then they are pirated.  The alternative method is request the purchase information from the department that provided them.

Comment: That's a good idea! I can do this to one machine only and whatever I discover will probably be the answer to the other ones as well. Thanks and, please, move this to an answer.

Comment: That is making an assumption. Even though it is likely the case, if something were happened to just one machine and you got that machine it would give a bad image of the whole. The same if that happened to one machine and you did not test that one, you'd think all were genuine while one or more aren't. If you want to be sure, deal with them all the same way. Another thing you can do is acuire the key of all machines and see if they're all the same. If they're all cracked, they're likely have the same key. Do check if they aren't a volume licence key.

Comment: By acquire I mean, use nirsoft's produkey to find out the s/n.

Comment: @LPChip - Is VLK even an option with Windows 7 Ultimate?

Comment: I understand the risks, but I'll probably not have the time to check it for all machines. But I'll use the suggestion of testing if the serial numbers are all the same, thanks.

Comment: @Ramhound yes its possible. Only the home basic and home premium cannot be VLK'd.

Comment: Well if it is VLK the keys will be the same but should be easy enough to verify if that key was purchased or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above commenters are incorrect.

**The only way to determine accurately determine if these machines are legitimately licensed are to contact whoever installed them and have them provide you with a copy of the license.**

- Formatting and reactivating the machine will be of no use. Irrespective of the many reasons a legitimate CD key may not reactivate cleanly, **having a legitimate CD key that activates does not prove you are entitled to use that software.**
- Checking if the CD keys are the same will be of no use. It is common to have the same, legitimate CD keys across multiple machines. Particularly in academic environments, legitimate copies of Windows from MSDN AA will often have the same key for an entire department. Even then, again, **it says nothing about whether you are entitled to use the software.**
- Checking the serial numbers will be of no use. Again, it tells you nothing about the actual license, and **it is normal to have the same S/N on multiple machines.**

All of that excepted:

---

tl;dr:

### The CD key is irrelevant. Having a "genuine" install does not mean you are entitled to use the software

The main complication here is the academic licensing environment. It is **not** suspicious to have different versions of Windows running on a machine than that on the sticker in universities. In fact, it's the norm. Universities normally have subscriptions to allow either volume licensing or free use of Windows through DreamSpark (previously MSDN AA). Most will buy a PC with the lowest/cheapest Windows option possible and install their own site-licensed copy of Enterprise or Ultimate as it's free.

Because of these bulk licensing deals, you **will** have lots of legally licensed machines with duplicate CD keys or serial numbers. But that's not the issue here.

The issue is that academic licenses for Windows and other Microsoft software is **restrictive**. In other words, different copies of Windows that look exactly the same are **not** permitted to be used in the same way.

Some examples:

- A Software Assurance agreement allows you to upgrade to any copy of Windows for free and can be used for any purpose. This would allow you to upgrade all Vista machines to Windows 7 (or 8+) machines across the university.
- Some limited SA agreements do the same, but forbid *commercial use*, so only *some* machines can be upgraded, and not machines used in other departments.
- A Dreamspark Premium (Previously MSDN AA) copy can give you (and your students) free standalone copies of Windows 7 Ultimate, but can only be used for *non-infrastructural* purposes. It can also only be used by *certain schools* so **transferring a computer between departments can invalidate the license, even if the CD key appears valid.**
- A Dreamspark Standard subscription provides a smaller selection of Windows versions but is available to all departments, but can only be used by students and not faculty.

Therefore, even if it looks valid and is not pirated, and activates correctly, it doesn't mean the license actually covers your use of it. Conversely, even if they CD key appears on multiple computers or does not cleanly activate, it does not mean it is pirated. You **must** refer to the original license conditions to actually know.